# Android - How do i execute code *after* a process is loaded

Tags: android

Basically when a menu item is pressed in my app it takes the user to a new screen.
But now i want to get a little bit of data online(a time/date) that will display somewhere on the page once it gets the data. 
At the moment the new screen doesnt load until the app gets the data which leaves a couple of second pause instead of loading the screen instantly and then showing the downloaded data when it finally has it.

Ive tried using the onStart method since that gets called after onCreate so i thought the page would be created and displayed and then onStart gets called but that doesnt happen, theres still lag between it loading because its getting the data online and then displays the page with it already loaded.

How can i sort this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For any kind of loading operation you should consider using the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in combination with the [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) in order to inform your user that you're performing something in the background.

Remember that you can only interact with the UIThread in the [`onPreExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) and [`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) method of your `AsyncTask`.

So in your case you'll probably want to fire the AsyncTask in the `onCreate()` method of your Activity, showing the ProgressDialog in the `onPreExecute()` method and then showing your information and hiding your ProgressDialog in the `onPostExecute`.

It's pretty much impossible to eliminate this lag you're talking about. So you better just handle it appropriately.

Hope this helps answers your question.